# Returning null from onCreateView?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

What happens if `onCreateView` returns null instead of View object?

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  ....
  return null;
}
```

I tested the application and it seemed to work fine even with `null`.

My question is: Why does only this Lifecycle function needs to return a `View` while the others don't need to and just use `void` and where it gets used?

Comment: What do you think "it seemed to work fine"? Are you even instantiating and using that fragment anywhere? It can't have worked. :D

Comment: "What happens if onCreateView returns null instead of View object?" -- the fragment will not manage any views. Usually, you do not bother overriding `onCreateView()` in this case. You will see this used with the "model fragment" pattern, where the fragment is being used to retain some objects across configuration changes, but does not have its own UI.

Comment: Ah, sorry yes, this time when I rebuilt the project it crashed. Not sure why it didn't crash the other time when it ran with making changes in code on-the-fly without rebuilding the complete project.

Comment: @CommonsWare: What do you mean by you don't bother overriding it? Isn't this where the graphical initializations such as inflate the fragment layout etc. take place? Yes, it is using MVC pattern but how does it relate with it exactly?

Comment: "What do you mean by you don't bother overriding it?" -- I mean just what I wrote. "Isn't this where the graphical initializations such as inflate the fragment layout etc. take place?" -- not if you are returning `null`. If you return `null`, your fragment does not have a UI. If your fragment has a UI, you return the root `View` of that UI, and that will not be `null`.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Is it also normal for application to crash if you return `null`?

Comment: If you try putting the non-existent `View` into a container, yes. IOW, when you add this fragment, use the version of `add()` that takes a tag, not a container ID.